# How I can change the circular iteration of active contour example to linear iteration for open contours?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour

[Here](http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/217) it says that if the end points are not connected the matrix should be simpler.I think that by changing only matrix I can achieve the linear iteration. So how do I can change the following original code to a linear version for open active contours ?

Below is the original code

```
% Populating the penta diagonal matrix
A = zeros(m,m);
b = [(2*alpha + 6 *beta) -(alpha + 4*beta) beta];
brow = zeros(1,m);
brow(1,1:3) = brow(1,1:3) + b;
brow(1,m-1:m) = brow(1,m-1:m) + [beta -(alpha + 4*beta)]; % populating a     template row
for i=1:m
  A(i,:) = brow;
  brow = circshift(brow',1)'; % Template row being rotated to egenrate     different rows in pentadiagonal matrix
end
 [L U] = lu(A + gamma .* eye(m,m));
Ainv = inv(U) * inv(L); % Computing Ainv using LU factorization
  end
```

This code is iterating circularly, but I want to iterate in a linear way. This means that the starting and ending points are not connected.
I would greatly appreciate if someone can provide any insights.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math/algebra  question, regarding the understanding of active contours, not a Matlab question.